# Unable to get Google App Engine PHP tutorial working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I'm following the [GAE PHP tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/getting-started/creating-guestbook) but I can't get the local dev server to respond properly.

I run it with

`dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php --host=192.168.33.44 ./`

and it starts up fine. When I view `http://192.168.33.44:8080/` the logs show

`INFO     2016-10-12 07:55:06,264 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

but I get a blank page. There's nothing in the tutorial explaining what to do if you have problems.

So far, I've:

- Tried PHP 5.5 and 5.6 (remi): no difference
- Put corrupt PHP in `helloworld.php`: no errors
- Changed the handler to `- url: /`: blank page on /, 404 page for any other URL
- Scoured Google Docs: no help
- Scoured Google: no help
- Asked the rubber duck: no help

I'm running Centos 7.2 via Vagrant and Google Cloud SDK 129.0.0.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]

Additional data as requested

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php


$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Sep 19 2016 13:45:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies


$ which python
/usr/bin/python


$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.5

$ cat app.yaml
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php


$ cat helloworld.php
<?php

echo 'Hello, World!';


$ dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php --host=192.168.33.44 ./


Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them, please run:
$ gcloud components update

INFO     2016-10-13 08:21:22,699 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-10-13 08:21:22,730 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:46453
INFO     2016-10-13 08:21:22,737 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://192.168.33.44:8080
INFO     2016-10-13 08:21:22,738 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2016-10-13 08:21:34,142 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Response Headers from Chrome when accessing http://192.168.33.44:8080/

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 08:21:34 GMT
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Development/2.0
```

I updated from 129 to 130 but the same problem exists

Comment: To cover the bases, post the full console output, post your app.yaml, and post your script handler file contents.

Also, verify which version of both PHP and Python you have installed.

Comment: Seems really unlikely, but if you omit the --host parameter and let that default to localhost, do you still have the same outcome?

Comment: Hi Chris! Do you get sensible output from port 8000? It's the local dev admin pages.

Comment: @BrettJ Tried accessing it locally via curl, but still got a blank response and a hit in the access logs.
Hi @Tom! Using `--admin_host=0.0.0.0` I can see int instances page. Starts with one entry. After the first request, shows 2 requests for the original instance (/ and favicon.ico) with another instance listed. Original instance goes up by 2 for every request, matching the access log activity

Comment: Try omitting the --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php flag. It isn't always required. I'm starting to think its something specific about Centos or Vagrant with Vagrant seeming more likely.

Comment: Running without the php_executable_flag fails to start. I'm gonna try it on a different OS, see if I have any luck.

Comment: I am replicating your problem on a Centos 7 virtual machine instance running on Compute Engine. Thanks for putting up with the questions. I am going to report this as a bug internally here at Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a trivial oversight...

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php --host=192.168.33.44 ./
```

Should have been

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi --host=192.168.33.44 ./
```

The App Engine **requires the php-cgi binary, not the cli one.** Ended up stumbling over it in the docs a while ago, but forgot to come back here and post the answer

Comment: thanks! that's a hard one and this seems the only answer I've found online. Google's documentation are quite poor, following their tutorial almost certain to end up in peril.